# Json.NET - JsonConvert.DeserializeObject is adding characters to string

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I am storing serialized models as JSON in a text file.

When I de-serialize an object using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyViewModel>(serializedViewModel)`, it turns a token within the model that I need for a uri from:

`...iVbdjdhasdfeeddDDCgxl6EpoZaw%2FiQGk%3D`

into
`...iVbdjdhasdfeeddDDCgxl6EpoZaw%253FiQGk%253D`.

What appears to be happening is when the JSON from text file is processed by `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyViewModel>(serializedViewModel)`, the "`%`" characters are replaced by "`%25`", which obviously renders the token invalid.

Is there a way to handle this and other special characters with json.NET settings, or a different way?

Comment: Where/How are you reading the value `DeserializeObject` method return ?

Comment: @Shyju For the Property in question (the token for the uri), I'm reading it from the uri that is ultimately sent to the View. I've also verified during debugging the before & after states of the token using the json visualizer in debugging, as well as the .txt file that the serialized ViewModel is saved in.

Comment: I thought perhaps I could just check each uri string after de-serialization, and replace all "%25" with "%", but I don't know if the Azure Blob SAS tokens can contain other special characters, and what will happen with those, so I don't know what and how many special cases I'd need to account for.

Comment: Json.Net is not doing that replacement.  What you are seeing is likely the result of [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).  Something is encoding your string before Json.Net even sees it.  Put a breakpoint at the line just before `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` and take a look at `serializedViewModel` to check it.  You will probably need to URL decode it before passing it to Json.Net.

Comment: Can you please share a [mcve]?

Comment: @BrianRogers I believe that's correct. According to the article you linked to, "Because the percent character ( % ) serves as the indicator for percent-encoded octets, it must be percent-encoded as %25 for that octet to be used as data within a URI." This is exactly what's happening. I've looked at the .txt file on Azure storage right before it's pulled and the string it contains is de-serialized, and it has just the non-escaped "%" character. The only other processing happening on this string from that point is where the .txt file is downloaded to a MemoryStream as follows:

Comment: `blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);                 string serializedData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());`